# Resource group '$system' could not be found on Azure

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-group

I have found $system resource group on cost analysis and it has some amount charged. But I couldn't find the resource or any log regarding the resource.

What is this $system resource and how its created. How to get logs of it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see -> [Azure Service Bus FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#i-have-a-service-bus-standard-namespace--why-do-i-see-charges-under-resource-group---system--)

> Azure Service Bus recently upgraded the billing components. Because of this change, if you have a Service Bus Standard namespace, you may see line items for the resource '/subscriptions/<azure_subscription_id>/resourceGroups/$system/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/$system' under resource group '$system'.

These charges represent the base charge per Azure subscription that has provisioned a Service Bus Standard namespace.

It's important to note that these charges aren't new, that is, they existed in the previous billing model too. The only change is that they're now listed under '$system'. It's done because of constraints in the new billing system that groups subscription level charges, not tied to a specific resource, under the '$system' resource ID.